# Creating Shape Files from SQL Server using Ogr2ogr

Tags: sql-server-2008, spatial, shapefile, ogr

I am trying to run the following code in a command window. The code executes, but it gives me no values in the .SHP files. The table has GeographyCollections and Polygons stored in a Field of type Geography. I have tried many variations for the Geography type in the sql statement - Binary, Text etc. but no luck.  The output .DBF file has data, so the connection to the database works, but the shape .Shp file and .shx file has no data and is of size 17K and 11 K, respectively.

Any suggestions?

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -overwrite c:\temp -nln Zip_States -sql "SELECT [ID2],[STATEFP10],[ZCTA5CE10],GEOMETRY::STGeomFromWKB([Geography].STAsBinary(),4326).STAsText() AS [Geography] FROM [GeoSpatial].[dbo].[us_State_Illinois_2010]" ODBC:dbo/GeoSpatial@PPDULCL708504
```

Answer (score 7):

ESRI Shapefiles can contain only a **single type of geometry** - Point, LineString, Polygon etc.

Your description suggests that your query returns multiple types of geometry, so restrict that first (using `STGeometryType() == 'POLYGON'`, for example).

Secondly, you're currently returning the spatial field as a text string using STAsText(), but you're not telling OGR that it's a spatial field so it's probably just treating the WKT as a regular text column and adding it as an attribute to the dbf file.

To tell OGR which column contains your spatial information you can add the "Tables" parameter to the connection string. However, there's no reason to do all the casting from WKT/WKB if you're using SQL Server 2008  - OGR2OGR will load SQL Server's native binary format fine.

Are you actually using SQL Server 2008, or Denali? Because the serialisation format changed, and OGR2OGR can't read the new format. So, in that case it's safer (but slower) to convert to WKB first.

The following works for me to dump a table of polygons from SQL Server to Shapefile:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -overwrite c:\temp -nln Zip_States -sql "SELECT ID, geom26986.STAsBinary() FROM [Spatial].[dbo].[OUTLINE25K_POLY]" "MSSQL:server=.\DENALICTP3;database=Spatial;trusted_connection=yes;Tables=dbo.OUTLINE25K_POLY(geom26986)"
```

Comment: The tables in the connection string did not solve my similar issue. The explicit cast though did. `GEOMETRY::STGeomFromWKB(shape.STAsBinary(), 26912)`

Comment: Changing the dialect to OGRSQL solved this double cast issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command

```
ogr2ogr shapeFileName.shp -overwrite -sql "select top 10 * from schema.table" "MSSQL:Server=serverIP;Database=dbname;Uid=userid;trusted_connection=no;Pwd=password" -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:4326
```